# bring checked check box values to other pages

Tags: java, android, eclipse, checkbox

i am currently developing a mobile application using eclipse. right now o am facing problem for bringing checked check box to new page...

this is code for the check box page...

page name : mcpakej1.xml

```
  `  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     tools:context="com.example.mobilecatering.MainActivity" >

   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
         android:id="@+id/pakejA1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"

      <CheckBox
         android:id="@+id/pakejA2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nasiputih1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nasiputih1"
    android:text="Nasi Beriyani" />

    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nasiberiyani1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nasiberiyani1"
    android:text="Nasi Minyak" />

     <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="Ayam Masak Kurma" />

     <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ayamkurma1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ayamkurma1"
    android:text="Ayam Masak Lemak" />

      <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ayamlemak1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ayamlemak1"
    android:text="Ayam Kari" />


      <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ayamkari1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ayamkari1"
    android:text="Ayam Rendang" />

     <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ayamrendang1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ayamrendang1"
    android:text="Ayam Masak Merah" />

     <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="Perut Air Asam" />


     <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/perutairasam1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/perutairasam1"
    android:text="Daging Masak Tomato" />


      <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dagingtomato1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dagingtomato1"
    android:text="Daging Masak Singgang" />

 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dagingsinggang1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dagingsinggang1"
    android:text="Daging Masak Merah" />


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="Kerabu Taugeh" />


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/kerabutaugeh1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/kerabutaugeh1"
    android:text="Pindang Kacang Panjang" />


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pindangkacang1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pindangkacang1"
    android:text="Jelatah" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/jelatah1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/jelatah1"
    android:text="Dalca Sayur" />


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA17"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dalcasayur1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dalcasayur1"
    android:text="Papadom" />

     <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA18"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:text="Kari Ikan" />


     <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA19"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pakejA18"
    android:layout_below="@+id/kariikan1"
    android:text="Kari Ikan Masin dan Nenas" />

    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA20"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:text="Sirap Ais" />


    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA21"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sirapais1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sirapais1"
    android:text="Oren" />


     <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA22"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pakejA21"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pakejA21"
    android:text="Teh Tarik" />


    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA23"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:text="Agar - Agar" />

    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA24"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/agaragar1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/agaragar1"
    android:text="Bubur Kacang Hijau" />

     <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pakejA25"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buburkacanghijau1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buburkacanghijau1"
    android:text="Kuih Muih" />   

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gobutton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/homebtn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/homebtn"
        android:background="@drawable/gobutton"
        android:onClick="goReceipt" />

         </LinearLayout>


      </ScrollView></RelativeLayout>`
```

this is the process in java.
page name : mcpakej1.java

```
     `package com.example.mobilecatering;


      import android.app.Activity;
       import android.content.Intent;
      import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.widget.CheckBox;

       public class mcpakej1 extends Activity 
       {

        CheckBox nsPutih,nsBeriyani,nsMinyak,aymKurma,aymLemak,aymKari,aymRendang,aymMerah,prtAsam, dggTomato, dggSinggang, dggMerah,kerabuTaugeh, pindangKacang,jelatah,dalcaSayur,papadom,kariIkan,ikanMasin, sirapAis, oren,tehTarik,agarAgar, buburKacang,kuih;

       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.mcpakej1);


      nsPutih       = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA1);
      nsBeriyani    = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA2);
      nsMinyak      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA3);
      aymKurma      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA4);
      aymLemak      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA5);
      aymKari       = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA6);
      aymRendang    = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA7);
      aymMerah      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA8);
      prtAsam       = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA9);
      dggTomato     = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA10);
      dggSinggang   = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA11);
      dggMerah      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA12);
      kerabuTaugeh  = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA13);
      pindangKacang = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA14);
      jelatah       = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA15);
      dalcaSayur    = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA16);
      papadom       = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA17); 
      kariIkan      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA18);
      ikanMasin     = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA19);
      sirapAis      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA20);
      oren          = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA21);
      tehTarik      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA22);
      agarAgar      = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA23);
      buburKacang   = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA24);
      kuih          = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pakejA25);

     }

public void goHome(View v){
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);}
}

public void goReceipt(View v) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), doReceipt.class);

    intent.putExtra("nsBeriyani", nsBeriyani.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("nsPutih", nsPutih.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("nsMinyak", nsMinyak.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("aymKurma", aymKurma.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("aymKari", aymKari.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("aymRendang", aymRendang.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("aymMerah", aymMerah.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("prtAsam", prtAsam.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("dggTomato", dggTomato.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("dggSinggang", dggSinggang.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("dggMerah", dggMerah.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("kerabuTaugeh", kerabuTaugeh.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("pindangKacang", pindangKacang.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("jelatah", jelatah.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("dalcaSayur", dalcaSayur.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("papadom", papadom.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("kariIkan", kariIkan.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("ikanMasin", ikanMasin.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("sirapAis", sirapAis.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("oren", oren.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("tehTarik", tehTarik.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("agarAgar", agarAgar.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("buburKacang", buburKacang.isChecked());
    intent.putExtra("kuih", kuih.isChecked());
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
    }
 }`
```

after user click button id goButton, this page will do this process.

page name = doReceipt.java

```
       package com.example.mobilecatering;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class doReceipt extends Activity

    {
     boolean nsPutih, nsBeriyani,nsMinyak,aymKurma,aymLemak,aymKari,aymRendang,aymMerah,prtAsam, dggTomato, dggSinggang, dggMerah,kerabuTaugeh, pindangKacang,jelatah,dalcaSayur,papadom,kariIkan,ikanMasin, sirapAis, oren,tehTarik,agarAgar, buburKacang,kuih;

      TextView tvOutput;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.receipt);

      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView17);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView18);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView20);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView23);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView24);
      tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView25);


      Bundle data = this.getIntent().getExtras();

      nsPutih=data.getBoolean("nsPutih");
      nsBeriyani=data.getBoolean("nsBeriyani");
      nsMinyak=data.getBoolean("nsMinyak");
      aymKurma=data.getBoolean("aymKurma");
      aymLemak=data.getBoolean("aymLemak");
      aymKari=data.getBoolean("aymKari");
      aymRendang=data.getBoolean("aymRendang");
      aymMerah=data.getBoolean("aymMerah");
      prtAsam=data.getBoolean("prtAsam");
      dggTomato=data.getBoolean("dggTomato");
      dggSinggang=data.getBoolean("dggSinggang");
      dggMerah=data.getBoolean("dggMerah");
      kerabuTaugeh=data.getBoolean("kerabuTaugeh");
      pindangKacang=data.getBoolean("pindangKacang");
      jelatah=data.getBoolean("jelatah");
      dalcaSayur=data.getBoolean("dalcaSayur");
      papadom=data.getBoolean("papadom");
      kariIkan=data.getBoolean("kariIkan");
      ikanMasin=data.getBoolean("ikanMasin");
      sirapAis=data.getBoolean("sirapAis");
      oren=data.getBoolean("oren");
      tehTarik=data.getBoolean("tehTarik");
      agarAgar=data.getBoolean("agarAgar");
      buburKacang=data.getBoolean("buburKacang");
      kuih=data.getBoolean("kuih");




      if(nsPutih==true)
      {

          tvOutput.setText("Nasi Putih");

      }

      if (nsBeriyani==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Nasi Beriyani");
      }

      if (nsMinyak==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Nasi Minyak");
      }

      if(aymKurma==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Ayam Masak Kurma");
      }

      if (aymLemak==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Ayam Masak Lemak");
      }

      if (aymKari==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Ayam Masak Kari");
      }

      if (aymRendang==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Ayam Masak Rendang");
      }

      if (aymMerah==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Ayam Masak Merah");
      }

      if (prtAsam==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Perut Air Asam");
      }

      if (dggTomato==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Daging Masak Tomato");
      }

      if (dggSinggang==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Daging Masak Singgang");
      }

      if (dggMerah==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Daging Masak Merah");
      }

      if (kerabuTaugeh==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Kerabu Taugeh");
      }

      if (pindangKacang==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Pindang Kacang");
      }

      if (jelatah==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Jelatah");
      }

      if (dalcaSayur==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Dalca Sayur");
      }

      if (papadom==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Papadom");
      }

      if (kariIkan==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Kari Ikan");
      }

      if (ikanMasin==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Kari Ikan Masin");
      }

      if (sirapAis==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Sirap Ais");
      }

      if (oren==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Oren");
      }

      if (tehTarik==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Teh Tarik");
      }

      if (agarAgar==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Agar Agar");
      }

      if (buburKacang==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Bubur Kacang");
      }

      if (kuih==true)
      {
          tvOutput.setText("Kuih Muih");
      }
    }

    }
```

this is the page where the checked check box should display text...
page name : receipt.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

      <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView7"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

      <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView11"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView13"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView14"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView16"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView17"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

      <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView18"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView19"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView20"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView21"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView22"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView23"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView25"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView24"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


   </LinearLayout>


      </ScrollView></RelativeLayout>
```

when i run eclipse's emulator, the page receipt.xml only display 1 checkbox value even if i checked on many checkbox.

help plz....tq

i tick on the checkbox Ayam Masak kurma and daging masak merah....
the output turn to be this way....

Ayam Masak Kurma

Daging Masak Merah

there are lot of spaces there...can u help me...i cannot upload the image of the emulator here...it says that i must get 10 point to post images....

Comment: create `tvOutput` textview as much as textview1,textview2.. you have. i mean tvOutput1,tvOutput2... tvOutputn. any way this is not the good way what you are doing..

Comment: Because tvOutput is only 1 Textview, you loose the value when you give it a new value every time you run: tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); while you should be using a distinct textView for all your textViews in the view. I also recommend you use a dictionary(map) for your values instead.

Comment: can u explain a bit more why `startActivityForResult(intent,0)` not `startActivity(intent)` and every time `request code` is `0`.

Comment: thank you u guys...it really works...i change the tvOutput to tvOutput1.......tvOutput25...the page receipt do display value of all the checkbox that i checked. now, there is a little bit problem occurs here. the output do not listed like a receipt. there is a space between the text displayed in the receipt page. i'll edit my question so that u guys can see the problem i am facing right now...tq...

Comment: guys...why i cannot upload image to my question?
i just want u to see what am i really trying to tell you...:(

Comment: Can you upload it to imgur and post the link the comments?

Comment: @user2156073 this is the link to the image that i had just uploaded into imgur....

http://imgur.com/8IY9YDy

Comment: can u help me to assign value to the checked check box? actually, i want to assign price for each check box. so that when user checked the check box, the price for all the checked check box can be total up in the receipt page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white spaces between your textviews are textviews that arent hidden, try to hide them when you have no data for them like:

```
    if(nsPutih==true) {
        tvOutput1.setText("Nasi Putih");
        tvOutput1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        tvOutput1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

However this is bad practice, you should try to dynamically create the textviews by putting them in a ListView. Also try to pass the data to the activity using a Map of objects.

Comment: sorry...what u mean by dynamically create the textviews by putting them in a ListView? should i get rid of the scrollView?

Comment: First you could try to implement the solution I said above, by hiding textviews with no text. After that you could experiment with new methods of loading and showing data since yours isn't optimal.

Comment: can u help me to assign value to the checked check box?
actually, i want to assign price for each check box. so that when user checked the check box, the price for all the checked check box can be total up in the receipt page

Answer (score -1):

with your intent try to pass your values with putextra and getextra method it will work